# How to add cross domain support to WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, http-headers, cross-domain

I'm trying to allow POST requests from my javascript app hosted at localhost:80 to a WCF REStful service hosted at a different port, but somehow it doesn't work. I've tried adding custom properties to the header, as well as adding it programatically in my service's `JSONData` method but I'm still getting '405 Method not allowed' in my response. What is the proper approach here ?

This is my interface :

```
namespace RestService
{
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        #region IRestServiceImpl Members

        public string JSONData()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return "Your POST request";
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and the service code :

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace RestService
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [ScriptMethod]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            UriTemplate = "export")]
        string JSONData();
    }
}
```

And finally the config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address ="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>  
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: It would be very good question if you describe what "but somehow it doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This worked better for me than the Web.config version:

Create a `Global.asax`

Add this method to the `Global.asax.cs`:

```
using System.Web;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ref: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/wcf/X8QN260412-Calling-Cross-Domain-WCF-Service-using-Jquery.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! finally got the exact solution, after searching a lot.

Comment: Great this finally worked after a couple of hours researching. Thanks bru!

Comment: You saved my lot of R&D hours. I really wanted to vote up more than one time :)..Thank you

Comment: As usual: What are the namespaces used? Please be specific, because my VS does not find it itslef.

Comment: namespace: System.Web

Comment: +1 Solution Worked for me. Earlier I have defined all CORS setting in web config but sometimes it works and sometimes not.

Answer (score 18):

Add these nodes to your Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ref: http://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/wcf-and-cors-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource/

Comment: Worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 9):

Enabling CORS for non-GET requests requires more than just setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header - it also needs to deal with *preflight* requests, which are `OPTIONS` requests which ask the server whether it's safe to perform operations which can potentially change data (e.g., POST, PUT, DELETE) before the actual request is sent.

I've written a blog post about adding CORS support for WCF. It's not the simplest of the implementations, but hopefully the code in the post can be simply copied / pasted into your project. The post can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/05/15/implementing-cors-support-in-wcf.aspx.

Comment: That's almost what I need. But I've noticed that it doesn't work if you send the data as a json. Your exabple page sends a single string value with the POST request. Or maybe it's because ExtJS handles the request data differently than jQuery :/

Comment: The example does send data as JSON - the inputs to the POST / PUT methods are *JSON strings* (notice that the input is wrapped in `"`'s). It works for objects as well, it's just that in the example the operation takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: I've changed the data in the test page to `            var data = {
                foo: "bar"
            };` and I'm getting 400 Bad request. I've checked the logs but nothing helpful there. So should I make changes also in the WCF itself to support it ?

Comment: Yes - in that case the operation must take a parameter of a user type, with a string field named 'foo'. If the operation takes a string, you should pass a string; you can only pass an object if the operation takes an object as a parameter.

Comment: I've tried changing argument type to Object but the same happens. Have you tried your example with objects in place of strings ? Though JSON is stringified anyway so this should work with a string. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It shouldn't be `Object`, but a data type which maps to the JSON you want to send. For example, if your class has a string property called "Foo", it should be able to accept the JSON object `{"Foo":"hello world"}` as input.

Comment: Ok, it was enough to just assign each property from the json to a new argument for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

The following .NET code (global.asax) has an important difference that in stead of *, it can be better to echo back the Origin domain because this enables authentication over CORS (e.g. NTLM / Kerberos) as well as the Preflight.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
        Response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

        if (Request.Headers["Origin"] != null)
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , Request.Headers["Origin"]);
        else
            Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "*");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the solutions above modify the CORS response to allow all sites to be CORS enabled by using the * attribute.  This seemed like a security risk to me as I wanted to control what sites were given access to my REST services.  I am hoping this may help others with the same type of issue.

I started by modifying the web.config file to include my allowed origin sites by using the SpecializedString collection which allows a string array to be stored in MySettings.  The code is in VB.Net so should port easily to c#, if desired.

```
<applicationSettings>
    <YourService.My.MySettings>
        <setting name="AllowedOrigins" serializeAs="Xml">
            <value>
                <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                    <string>http://localhost:62087</string>
                    <string>https://yourallowedorign2:3344</string>
                </ArrayOfString>
            </value>
        </setting>
    </YourService.My.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

And in the Global.asax.vb file, I made the following adjustments to the Application_BeginRequest code.

Note the support function to get the Allowed Origins

```
Private allowedOrigins As String()

Public Function GetAllowedOrigins() As String()
    Dim mySetting As StringCollection = My.Settings.AllowedOrigins

    If mySetting IsNot Nothing Then
        ' If you're using .NET 3.5 or greater:
        Return mySetting.Cast(Of String)().ToArray()

        ' Otherwise:
        Dim array(mySetting.Count - 1) As String
        mySetting.CopyTo(array, 0)

        Return array
    Else
        Dim strEmpty() As String = Enumerable.Empty(Of String).ToArray
        Return strEmpty
    End If
End Function

Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    Dim origin As String = sender.Request.Headers("Origin")
    If origin IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim originURI As Uri = New Uri(origin)
        Dim requestHost As String = originURI.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + originURI.Host
        If originURI.Port <> 80 Then
            requestHost += ":" + originURI.Port.ToString
        End If

        If allowedOrigins Is Nothing Then
            allowedOrigins = GetAllowedOrigins()
        End If
        If allowedOrigins IsNot Nothing AndAlso allowedOrigins.Contains(requestHost) Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", requestHost)
            If HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod = "OPTIONS" Then
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000")
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

One other caveat that I found is that I needed to add the X-Requested-With value in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.  If you get a CORS error, check that header first to see if you need additional options.

I hope this helps other that may be frustrated by this all too common issue.