# unable to hit service from IIS

Tags: c#, jquery, iis, localhost, web-hosting

when i hit a service using localhost the application run properly but when i hit it with IIS it doesnot reach to that service code

code run properly when hit with localhost .. similarly when use iis , it doesnot even hit the service

1.var urlreport = "http://localhost:57451/Service1.svc/";
2.var urlreport = "http://206.19.38.20/report/Service1.svc/";

when the first link use to hit the service application run properly ..
problem occur when i use 2nd link(2).

thanks in advance .

Comment: http://206.19.38.20/report/Service1.svc/ => http://206.19.38.20/Service1.svc/

Comment: report = alias name without this IIS alias name is it working fine ???

Comment: POST http://206.19.38.20/Service1.svc/getlabreport
 
   
error report :
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://206.19.38.20/Service1.svc/getlabreport. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/how-to-add-cross-domain-support-to-wcf-service

Answer (score 0):

i think incorrect url become
http://206.19.38.20/Service1.svc/" as per "http://localhost:57451/Service1.svc/"
remove the report from given code.

Comment: Actually i try every possible way .. the first link open when i open the report using solution file of vs2010 .so it has no report folder. when i hit it with iis it contain a alias name 'report' is that alias name