# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2.  I have created a service in my local machine in WCF and runs it.  A simple method is created that returns a string, codes is shown below.

```
    public string JSONData(string id)
    {
        return "You requested product is " + id;
    }
```

Now I want to access that service in my Angular2 app in my service.ts file.  Code in accessing the service method is shown below:

```
   testService(){
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:49753/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/4')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(data => console.log("Testing service" + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

But when I run the codes, I got the error below: 
"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http...."

Is there a way to call my WCF service without hosting my service in other machine?

Comment: You need to enable CORS for your service. Perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14047754/6680611

Comment: If you use angular-cli, you can simply add a proxy and don't worry about CORS headers.

Comment: @MikeOne you might want to add that as answer - with a short example.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this problem as header which you are sending is not matched with the headers in backend

So let suppose In frontend you sending headers

```
contentHeaders = new Headers();
contentHeaders.append('Authorization', 'Basic YW5ndWxhci13YXJlaG91c2Utc2VydmljZXM6MTIzNDU2');
contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
contentHeaders.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

So those headers like 'Authorization','Content-type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' should matched with your header allow in backend.

So in backend 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' should have all above headers 
see below

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization,content-type,Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
```

So here in Access-Control-Allow-Headers you have to passed all headers which you send from frontend : 'Authorization','Content-type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

It will work perfectly when you use above concept.