# Angular2 call WCF service fails

Tags: rest, angular, wcf

Below angular code which calls the WCF service.

```
public customLogin(user: string, pass: string): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ method: "POST",headers: headers,body: user} );

    return this.http.post(this.url, user, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

WCF service url in local

'http://localhost:34244/CitizenService.svc/register';

It fails with 405 error.

[image]

Anyone knows what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a CORS issue here. The request you're showing is actually a pre-flight OPTIONS request (not yet the actual POST request)and the 405 - Method not allowed indicates that WCF doesn't allow the OPTIONS method.

Maybe this is also helpful: [How to add cross domain support to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/how-to-add-cross-domain-support-to-wcf-service)