# How to post to a development web API from outside Visual Studio without CORS issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors

I have an old project running happily in VS2019 - a RESTful web service and some javascript code to access the service. It was written a while ago, using a much older version of VS.

I can do POST requests with JSON data in the development environment - when the project starts running, I have set it to open `index.html` and start the web service.
However if I just start the service (by selecting 'don't open a page, wait for a request...') and then access the service from outside of VS, I am getting a CORS error - presumably because the client and server are now running on different ports.

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

I have read *a lot* about CORS (there are so many posts on here!) and as a result have included the following in `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST,OTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

I have also found [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) which explains how to set up CORS on ASP.NET but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation (I have installed the suggested CORS package with NuGet, but I don't have any c# configuration code in my source - the only config is `web.config').

So, how can I allow access to my service (in the dev environment) from outside of VS? I need to do this because I want to completely rewrite the client code using VSCode and Vue.

I *could* start a new web app project in VS2022, using the latest technologies, and copy my server code accross. I am prepared to do this if it will solve the CORS problem - but is there an easier way?

**[edit]**
In response to @quentin's comments:

- I mentioned VS2019 because it seemlessly integrates the client JScript with the server API *without* CORS errors
- Am I using ASP.NET? I *think* so, although there's not much mention of it in the project. The debugger is set to ASP.NET, and the code works well on the remote (production) server which is ASP.NET
- Server language is c#, .NET 4.5.2, running on IIS Express

Comment: "in VS2019" — Your choice of IDE shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: "how to set up CORS on ASP.NET" — Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about the server side programming languages, frameworks, and their versions. (And apply suitable tags, beyond just [tag:cors], to the question).

Comment: Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/) (the accepted `global.asax` answer)