# How to enable CORS in WCF?

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, cors

I have a WCF service (the project is a WCF service library), the service works, I can call this service form Insomnia but when i try to use it in my next.js app, I get this error:

Access to fetch at 'http://miURL' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:          Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I know this is a CORS problem but I don't know hot to enable CORS in my WCF service.

This is my code:

JavaScript:

```
const test = async () => {
    const peticion = await fetch('URL', {
            method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
    const respuesta = await peticion.json()
    console.log(respuesta);
  }
```

My Service Code:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string leerHuella()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        string value = form1.leerHuellaForm();
        return value;
    }
}
```

My iService code:

```
public interface IService1

    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string leerHuella();
    }
```

My App.config:

```
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
    <enableWebScript />
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

If someone can help me, that would be great

I have tried some configurations from various tutorials bot none have worked so far.
As a note, I don't have an asax.cs file and I cant add one, the option is not available in my add item window.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add cross domain support to WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047754/how-to-add-cross-domain-support-to-wcf-service)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but no, i can't add an asax.cs file and i already tied adding the webServer configuration to my App.config but i had cero changes

Comment: There are multiple answers to the question I linked. I am no expert in wcf, but could you modify your app.config with the second answer’s recommendation? I also don’t know why you cannot add an asax.cs file.

Comment: I already tried that configuration, nothing changed and i cant add a asax.cs because mi project is a WCF library and not a  WCF application

Comment: For future reference, you should mention everything you have tried so that people can give more helpful advice. Given that this should work, I recommend you start a new wcf project, and add back parts until it stops working. In this case, you may find that the config can only be changed when you are creating a wcf application instead of a wcf library. This would make it easier to find an answer and easier for people to answer your question in the case it doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

Add two new files, **Global.asax** and **Global.asax.cs**

Global.asax:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Wcf.Global" Language="C#" %>
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
 
namespace Wcf
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
 
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");
 
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
 
        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
 
        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to this document:
[Enabling CORS in WCF](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/845474/Enabling-CORS-in-WCF)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but when i manually add the Global.asax to the project i get an error saying that the assembly references for the .Net Framework of destination cannot be found.

Comment: You can try 1. Add Reference 2.Nuget related packages to the project

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also occur if your **WCF** is deployed on **IIS** and is not configured.

1. Select the corresponding project in IIS and select **HTTP Response Headers**.

[image]

2.Add the appropriate information

[image]