GetAsync call in Blazor WebAssembly fails
I believe something which I don't understand about Blazor coming from Windows Forms development is happening here. I am trying to get data from an API which I know is working and delivering data correctly to another application. To me, it appears that the code is being terminated prior to allowing the async call to finish.
It crashed on the httpClient.GetAsync line. For testing purposes this call is running when the page loads with the OnInitializedAsync function.
I have followed 2 different tutorials but both yield the same result of the .GetAsync call failing: https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-httpclient/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffrGQwICEIY
Please help.
Thanks!
Service class:
public class RecipeService : IRecipeService
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    private string baseURL = clConstants.SERVER_PATH;
    private string apiEndPoint = "getRecipeByID/";

    public RecipeService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    async Task<List<clRecipe>> IRecipeService.getRecipeByID(int id)
    {
        ConfigureHTTPClient();

        string URL = clConstants.SERVER_PATH + apiEndPoint + id.ToString();

        // Crashes on this line of code
        var res = httpClient.GetAsync(URL).Result; 
    }
}

Interface:
public interface IRecipeService
{
    //Task<IEnumerable<clRecipe>> getRecipeByID(int id);
    Task<List<clRecipe>> getRecipeByID(int id);
}

Function in the Razor page:
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    recipe = await RecipeService.getRecipeByID(currentCount);
}

Program.cs (added the following line):
builder.Services.AddScoped<IRecipeService, RecipeService>();

UPDATED CODE
Interface
public class RecipeService : IRecipeService
{
    private readonly string apiEndPoint = "GetRecipeByID/";

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient() => httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MainApi");

    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new()
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };

    public RecipeService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<List<clRecipe>>getRecipeByID(int id)
    {
        string URL = apiEndPoint + id.ToString();

        var response = await CreateHttpClient().GetAsync(URL, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var recipe = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<clRecipe>>(result, jsonOptions);
        return recipe;

    }
}


public interface IRecipeService
{
    Task<List<clRecipe>> getRecipeByID(int id);
}

Program
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MainApi", options =>
{
     options.BaseAddress = new Uri(clConstants.SERVER_PATH);
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRecipeService, RecipeService>();

PAGE
@inject IRecipeService RecipeService

private List<clRecipe> recipe { get; set; }

public interface IRecipeService
{
    Task<List<clRecipe>> getRecipeByID(int id);
}

Error in the browser now:
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

I have my API with WCF (I think as it was written a decade ago. ) Seems like I have to implement CORS at the server side. Whats the best way to go about this. Write a new API from scratch ?

What does URL point to? Are you sure you return the value you're expecting?

Why aren't you using var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL); in your service class? It's an async method, so this would be the preferred way to go - avoiding the .Result approach ... also - if those methods should be callable from the "outside", you probably need to make them public on your interface and in your service class ...

Rest API works as expected.

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL); has the same behavior and crashes.

Try to add details for "it crashes". There should be something to see in the console or network tabs (dev tools, F12).

Also, var response will have an error code.

has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Added additional details to the original post. Thanks.

Different problem now, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14047754/60761

        var res = httpClient.GetAsync(URL).Result; 

Is classic deadlock code. It blocks the thread that is doing the scheduled work.  GetAsync is in the queue behind the code waiting for the result.
Unless you have an in-depth working knowledge of async behaviour, KISS - stick to async and await.
        var res = await httpClient.GetAsync(URL); 

You should also look at use the IHttpClient Factory.  @wiseotter's answer provides more details on restructuring your code.
There are many articles and answers on the subject - For example, see 'await' works, but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks

Unfortuantely I tried this and it has the same behavior. I pasted updated code above if you have any thoughts?

What actual error are you getting?  Check for errors in the Browser Console Log in Developer Tools - .

Didn't realize I could see an messages. Here's what it says ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Added additional details to the original post. Thanks.

Different problem now as remarked by @HenkHolterman.  See his comment.

Hope all of this helps!
RecipeService & IRecipeService
public interface IRecipeService
{
    Task<ClRecipe> GetRecipeByID(int id);
}

public class RecipeService : IRecipeService
{
    private readonly string apiEndPoint = "GetRecipeByID/";

    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;
    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient() => httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MainApi");
    
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new()
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };

    public RecipeService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<ClRecipe?> GetRecipeByID(int id)
    {
        //ConfigureHTTPClient();

        //string URL = clConstants.SERVER_PATH + apiEndPoint + id.ToString();
        
        string URL = $"{apiEndPoint}?id={id}";

        var response = await CreateHttpClient().GetAsync(URL, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        
        var recipe = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ClRecipe>(result, jsonOptions);
        return recipe;

    }
}

Recipe.razor
@page "/recipe"
@inject IRecipeService recipeService

<h3>Recipe</h3>
@if (recipe is null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    <p>@recipe.RecipeID</p>
    <p>@recipe.RecipeName</p>
}

@code {
    private ClRecipe? recipe { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // recipe = await recipeService.GetRecipeByID(15); // not found
        
        recipe = await recipeService.GetRecipeByID(5);
        if (recipe is null)
        {
            recipe = new ClRecipe
            {
                RecipeID = -420,
                RecipeName = "Not Found"
            };
        }
    }
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("MainApi", options =>
{
    //options.BaseAddress = new Uri(clConstants.SERVER_PATH);
    options.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7206/");
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRecipeService, RecipeService>();

Supporting Links / Reads
IHttpClientFactory Info
Making Requests with HttpClient
Dependency Injection
await versus .Result related Stack question
HttpClient vs IHttpClientFactory

I believe I followed this and only changed it minorly for the specific syntax I need however It behaves the same as before. I pasted the new code above for better readablity. Any thoughts?

as the others were saying in the comments on the original post some error message or more details about the crash would help a lot with solving the problem.
Looks like you're trying to get 1 recipe by id, but you are deserializing a list of them

My API currently generates the JSON as an array if you request 1 or multiple separated by a , which I know is odd but works for me at this point.

Added additional details to the original post. Thanks.
